# Why does java promote long parameter to float/double when there's no method which accepts long?

Tags: java, type-conversion, overloading

Here's a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) which demonstrates the described (IMHO, weird) behavior:

```
public class Test {

   public static void print(int param) {
       System.out.println("int");
   }

   public static void print(float param) {
       System.out.println("float");
   }

   public static void print(Long param) { //<--Wrapper type
       System.out.println("Long");
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       long param = 100L;
       print(param);  // output == float
   }
}
```

Why does java do that?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[*Java Language Specification*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2) is pretty clear on that (emphasis mine):

> #### 15.12.2 Compile-Time Step 2: Determine Method Signature
>
> [...]
>
> 1. The first phase (§15.12.2.2) performs overload resolution **without permitting
>      boxing or unboxing** conversion [...] If no applicable method is found during this phase then processing continues
>      to the second phase. [...]
> 2. The second phase (§15.12.2.3) performs overload resolution while **allowing
>      boxing and unboxing** [...]
> 3. The third phase (§15.12.2.4) allows overloading to be combined with variable
>      arity methods, boxing, and unboxing.

That is, in the first step only `print(int)` and `print(float)` can be appropriate. The latter matches and no further investigation is made.

---

The reason for such rules is explained in JLS as well:

> This guarantees that any calls that were valid in the Java programming language before Java SE 5.0 are not considered ambiguous as the result of the introduction of variable arity methods, implicit boxing and/or unboxing.

Imagine that your `Test` class was compiled against Java 1.4 (before autoboxing). In that case it's clear: `print(float)` must be chosen (assuming we agree why `long` to `float` is considered safe and can be implicit...) as `print(Long)` is completely incompatible with `long` argument.

Later you compile the same code against Java 5+. The compiler can:

- choose `print(Long)` as more "*obvious*" in this context. Thus after upgrading to Java 5 your program behaves differently...
- yield compilation error as the call is ambiguous. Thus, previously correct code is no longer compiling under Java 5 (which AFAIR is never the case)
- ...or preserve old semantics and call the same method as under Java 1.4

You should now understand why `print(float)` is used - because it would have been chosen under Java 1.4. And Java has to be backward compatible.

Comment: I don't consider the first overload a better match than the last two (except the first overload can be performed with appropriate downcasting)

Comment: FYI If you remove the `float` overload from the example, it chooses `Long` over `int`: http://ideone.com/x6HZ1Q

Comment: @PaulBellora: thanks for this interesting observation, it proves that rules above work. `print(int)` alone is completely incompatible with `long` (try removing `print(Long)` - compilation error), so the compiler moves to phase 2.

Comment: +1 This appears to state that it does because it does.  Can you clarify *why* it does in your opinion?

Comment: @PeterLawrey: you correctly pointed out backward compatibility, I included some more thorough explanation, thanks!

Answer (score 12):

The reason it chooses `float` over `Long` is that autoboxing was added later and for backward compatibility reasons it would have to make the same call it always did.

Answer (score 7):

Tomasz Nurkiewicz points to the relevant part of the specification ([15.12.2 in Java SE 7 JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2)), but why do that? For backward compatibility source code that targets 1.4 and earlier should continue to call the same overloaded method. Therefore, features of 1.5 have to be ignored, and only if the code wouldn't otherwise compile should autoboxing be considered.

As to why conversion from `long` to `float` may be implicit - that is just a questionable design choice.

Comment: The fundamentally problematic design choice was deciding that implicit conversions which are ever available must be legal (without a diagnostic) even in cases where an overloaded method or operator can take multiple types.  That design choice led to Java requiring a silly cast for `float f=(float)(1.0/10.0);`, but not for `double d=1.0f/10.0f;`, nor for `if (f==d)...`. The cast in the first expression does nothing to enhance readability nor call attention to a potential mistake; by contrast, if I were conducting a code review and code was *supposed* to have the semantics implied by...

Comment: ...the latter two, I would want the second expression written as `double f=(double)(float)(1.0f/10.0f) and the third as `if ((double)f==d)`, since in the former case the *intended* meaning could likely have been to perform the division as `double` (and a cast to `double`, by itself, wouldn't clarify that); in the latter case, without a typecast, it's unclear whether the comparison is intended to test whether `f` holds the value it would hold if copied from `d`, or whether `d` holds the value it would hold if copied from `f`. Restricting the use of implicit conversions with overloading...

Comment: ...would have let the compiler perform implicit conversions when they made sense, and squawk at places where they don't.  I think the behavior might be improved without breaking compatibility if options could be set for all or part of a source file.

Answer (score 5):

See documentation

[Chapter 5. Conversions and Promotions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html)

> 5.1.2. Widening Primitive Conversion
>
> 19 specific conversions on primitive types are called the widening
>   primitive conversions:
>
> - byte to short, int, long, float, or double
> - short to int, long, float, or double
> - char to int, long, float, or double
> - int to long, float, or double
> - long to float or double
> - float to double

So conversion form `long` to `float` is along with the rules.